# raycaster-intersected fires event when loading page

Tags: aframe

Short question... I have an eventlistener that listens to raycaster-intersected and a laser controls. It fires the event immediately when I start the page. Anybody any clues why and how to prevent this?

(on my object with class .rayTarget)

```
this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersected", function(){
// random code
});
```

(in my scene)

```
< a-entity oculus-go-controls=""  laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects:.rayTarget;"></a-entity>
```

Using Aframe master branche (June 2018)

Currently I added a setTimeout that does "solve" the problem, but this doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the hands are pointing at something while the scene is being loaded. Maybe until their position is set according to the controller readings.

If you want a better solution than `setTimeout` you can set the raycaster with `setAttribute("raycaster", .....` when the scene, or window are loaded:

You can wait until the window is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("The window is loaded")
}
```

---

or wait until the scene is loaded

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("loaded", (e) => {
      console.log("The scene is loaded")
    })
  }
})
```

---

You can set up your stuff then, or switch some `loaded` flags in your code. Check them out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6ncrkm1/20/).